# HIde/Show multiple objects with 1 button in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a chatbot widget for my website 
The problem is the chat with us button shows only the bot not the close button too

this is what I tried

```
                <input id="chat" type="button" onclick="Show();" value="Chat with us" />
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                            function Show()
                            {document.getElementById("bot").style.display="block";}
                            {document.getElementById("close").style.display="block";}
                            {document.getElementById("chat").style.display="none";}

                    </script>
```

it should show both the bot and close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing your function after the first line (only `bot` will hide). Remove the other braces:

```
function Show() {
  document.getElementById("bot").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("close").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("chat").style.display = "none";
}
```